# C# Console Application connecting to a 1.1 web service (WCF/WSE/WebRequest)

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, proxy, wsdl

I have been provided with a SOAP 1.1 `WSDL` and a Password protected P12 X509 certificate to connect to a web service to periodically transmit records. I have also been provided with a how to guide to sign the message using the X509. The example provided illustrates how to sign the message and provide appropriate security message headers. The sample code is in Java, and includes functions for signing the message which interact with the SOAP message directly.

The application I'm writing is a c# console app with entity framework elements to retrieve the data.

My question is related to the best approach for tackling this problem:

> 1. Use WCF with static configuration where possible.
> 2. Use WCF with programmatic configuration (e.g. using custom
>      MessageHeaders).
> 3. Use WebRequest/WebResponse and craft the messages manually.
> 4. Use WSE 3.0 and convert the WSDL to a proxy class using the older command line tools.

I've been investigating the WCF routes - WCF is ideal if you control both sides of the equation - but the articles are thinning out for my specific use case.